# Hidding UILabel on Init

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I'm having a problem with this basic code:

```
-(id)init{
self = [super init];
if(self){
    self.mensaje = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0)];
    [self.mensaje setText:@"He vuelto"];

    [self.view addSubview:self.mensaje];
    [self.mensaje setHidden:YES];
}
return self;
}
```

All the code works fine, except `[self.mensaje setHidden:YES];`. The Label is always shown at start.

I  hope could help me, this is basic, but necessary!!

Good luck!

Comment: You could try to hide it in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: A mí me encanta que tu código esté en Spanglish. `c:`

Comment: jeje, se me ha pasado, lo he copiado directamente. Thank you very much! jeje

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is in the wrong place. You shouldn't be creating and working with views in the initializer of a view controller (assuming the above code is inside a view controller class).

instead, do the following:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // init any state other than views
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.mensaje = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0)];
    [self.mensaje setText:@"He vuelto"];
    [self.view addSubview:self.mensaje];
    [self.mensaje setHidden:YES];
}
```

This also assumes you are using ARC. If not, you need to add `autorelease` as follows:

```
    self.mensaje = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0)] autorelease];
```